# xmlHttp responseText returns php file rather than the result of running the php script

Tags: php, html

I have the following programs, test.html and test.php

test.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">


class NameForm extends React.Component {


    componentDidMount(){
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
                console.log(xmlHttp.responseText)
            }
        }.bind(this)

        xmlHttp.open("GET","test.php",true)
        xmlHttp.send(null)
        event.preventDefault()
    }


    render() {
        return (<div/>)
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <NameForm />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);


</script>
</body>
```

test.php

```
<?php
echo "this is a test"
?>
```

When I open the html page I get the content of the php script written in the console rather than the result of running the php script as I was expecting, that is to say, in the console I get this:

```
<?php
echo "this is a test"
?>
```

rather than this:

```
this is a test
```

Why is this? How can I fix it? Thanks,

Also in case this is relavent I am running this locally using python SimpleHTTPServer

Comment: Seems like your php is not parsing. If you are calling a php script sitting on your folder, it won't work. You'll need a set up like WAMP server at least

Comment: what is that and how do I do it? can I do that locally?

Comment: You need to install/configure PHP with some web server (apache or nginx)

Comment: Do you have php installed on your computer? If so, stop python SimpleHTTPServer,  open terminal/command prompt, `cd` to the folder, then run `php -S localhost:8000`. Then access your page from http://localhost:8000

Comment: thanks ibex, that works great

Comment: if you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP** is a server sided language so your browser can not parse it unlike html , Javascript or ... that your browser can run them.

**So you need a server to run PHP.** (Installing PHP)

On windows you can use [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) to have it locally easily and run your codes. And make your computer your server to test your codes...

Another way is to install PHP manually and run it.

But if you want to have real server and host sites, it is more complicated ...

*PS:if you want to just test your codes without change your computers configuration there are free hostings you can use them ...*

You can read more at : *[What you need to get started with PHP](https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p2.html)*

Comment: you didn't mention that he has many mistakes in the `JavaScript` code also.